# substr_replace all occurrences inside big string

Tags: php, replace, substring

I have the following code, I am trying to do a regular expression replace inside the $query variable, and I need to replace all occurrences of "Hello" with "Bye". What is wrong with this code?

```
<?php

ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 116000);

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.mysite.com.br/index.php?option=com_xxxx&format=xml');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);


if (strlen($query) > 95000){
echo "OK";
substr_replace ($query ("hello","bye",0));
file_put_contents('/home/myuser/mysite.com/xml/file.xml',$query);
} 
else 
{
echo "Error";
}

?>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with php but from http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php it looks like your syntax should be `$query = substr_replace ($query ,"hello","bye",0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is actually the command you are looking for;

```
$query = str_replace ("hello","bye",$query);
```

Comment: i need to replace regular expression inside $query so I dont think this will work but i am trying now.. thanks

Comment: forget what i wrote above, your solution is working, anyway I used  "$query2 = str_replace ("hello","bye",$query);"
thank you...

Comment: @ol30cean0 Maybe I didn't understand your issue then.  There is a command [preg_replace] [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php] for regular expressions if you need something more complicated